# 15.10 x64 Ubuntu Live CD crashes on MSI GX70

Tags: live-usb, msi

I am trying to install Lubuntu 15.10 64 bit in my MSI GX70 laptop which has Windows 7 preinstalled. I load the ISO onto the USB drive using UNetbootin and then boot as I used to do with my old laptop. However, the live CD session works for a few seconds and then crashes. I haven't tried directly installing it. I also pressed tab when the boot options come up and typed ´nomodeset´ but to no avail. What must I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unetbootin is known to not create the media properly.

Use the built-in tool diskpart from within Windows OS.

Open command prompt as administator and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO file - copy the whole content to the USB drive.

**Update addressing your comment that the Ubuntu Live seesion crashes :**

Boot from Ubuntu installation media. Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `radeon.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Live desktop. Perform the installation.

When finished boot the Ubuntu system. Select the Ubuntu boot menu entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `radeon.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into Ubuntu system. Install the AMD drivers.

Reboot ... from now on you don't have to add the boot parameter anymore.

Note :

Set a 'space' between the last sign in the linux line and `radeon.modeset=0`.

Comment: With this method, I can't even boot. I tried using LiLi still the same result I am afraid. I am booting in legacy mode by the way.

Comment: @Ekoji : Which dedicated graphics adapter do you have in  MSI GX70 - AMD Radeon or NVIDIA GEFORCE ?

Comment: AMD Radeon HD 8650G

Comment: Also what I meant when I said 'same result' was that the live cd session crashes.

Comment: I can't even boot using the method you suggested. Says remove the drive and try again. I used unetbootin again and clicked [TAB]. Then the command line appeared and I typed radeon.modeset=0. No change

Comment: @Ekoji : Strange ... it should work, it does in nearly all cases ... here is one - the only difference is that this computer has NVIDIA graphics -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/750666/problem-with-installing-ubuntu-15-10-on-msi/750679#750679 - maybe you have to change some settings in BIOS . :)

Comment: Now it did. Changed the boot mode to UEFI and worked. I also tried it using UNetBootin. I forgot to add the space at the end.