# Problem with Installing Ubuntu 15.10 on MSI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I have MSI ge60 2pe. I am facing big problem,whenever I try to boot USB it is obviously showing me options such as "try without installation" etc. However whenever I choose to install or try without installation system just reboot after like 30 sec. I was able to boot for a few times however it crashed during installation. I have already tried Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3(giving me 2 errors during check.),unetbootin-windows-613(giving 1 error),and win32 does not show any problems during checking,but still reboot no matter what. To be honest I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Press `e` when you have the TRY option highlighted. Put `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the line beginning with `linux`. Press `F10` to boot. You'll have to do that when Ubuntu is installed until you install proprietary drivers.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. Computer just rebooted as before.

Comment: Try using [Rufus](http://Rufus.akeo.ie) to make the USB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, 3rd party tools are known to often not create the Ubuntu installation media properly.
Use diskpart - this tool is known to create a proper installation media and is included in Windows.

Open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO file - copy the whole content to the USB drive.

Second, the MSI GE60 2PE should have a dedicated NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 860M graphics adapter.

Boot from Ubuntu installation media. Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Live desktop. Perform the installation.

When finished boot the Ubuntu system. Select the Ubuntu boot menu entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into Ubuntu system. Install the NVIDIA drivers.

Reboot ... from now on you don't have to add the boot parameter anymore.
Do not forget to disable hibernation and fast startup in Windows before ...

Comment: I have followed your steps and still after I type nouveau.modeset=0 and reboot there is that ubuntu logo and after something around 30 sec computer reboot again.

Comment: @Cerber : When you have Windows installed in EFI mode, make sure that you select the Ubuntu USB entry marked with UEFI in front and please also check in BIOS whether there is a switch to temporarily disable the NVIDIA chip during the installation process and if you can disable Secure Boot, in case yes, do it. :)

Comment: I have tried number of times and still either it crash on ubuntu logo or reboot. There is no such option to disable NVIDIA chip temporary. I have disabled secure boot and fast boot.

Comment: @Cerber : Please make sure that hibernation is disabled as well - open command prompt as administrator and execute : powercfg /h off and do not connect an external monitor before the installation is finished. Shutdown the computer completely - do not restart - then turn the PC back on and boot from USB. :)

Comment: Unfortunately still. Computer is just booting again when ubuntu is loading. I have disabled hibernation, turn off computer then in bios I have changed order so usb was first and finally I was trying to boot it using nouveau.modeset=0. Still problem occurred.

Comment: @Cerber : Maybe there is another switch in BIOS - every hardware is different ... Make sure to set a space between the last sign in the linux line and nouveau.modeset=0 - it should work, it does in nearly all cases.

Comment: And there you go. I haven't typed space before...Silly mistake.Now I'm about to install. According to graphic adapter, where should I get it from ?

Comment: @Cerber : Nice to read this ! Well, this would be another question you should ask, but here you find the instructions to install the drivers -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/738822/nvidia-graphic-card-disappeared-after-bug-with-nvidia-prime-ubuntu-14-04/738905#738905 - you can skip step 1 of course ! :)

Comment: Ok so I have install ubuntu now how can i boot to it ? I have changed windows boot manager to ubuntu, however when i leave it like that i am not able to boot into windows because when i choose windows it says there is a problem with os. however when i switch it everything works fine.

Comment: @Cerber : Set Ubuntu as the default operating system to boot in BIOS. There should be a Windows entry in the GRUB boot menu from which you alternatively can boot into the Windows operating system. :)

Comment: I have done it. When I am trying to boot to windows it says that my computer need to be fixed.

Comment: @Cerber : This really is a different question you may ask ... or you stick with the solution you provided in your comment before. But I am quite sure that this can be solved within the UEFI settings in the BIOS. :)